# psycopg2 error in ubuntu 18.0

Tags: xubuntu, python

I am trying to Install psycopg2 in my ubuntu 18.0 version but I am getting error like this.

I am Using ubuntu 18.0 version,

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /home/devfwecoapproot/ecoappapis/fwecovenv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, 
tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mq7sxbje/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; 
__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mq7sxbje/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, 
'"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip- 
wheel-k_vu4p_s
cwd: /tmp/pip-install-mq7sxbje/psycopg2/
Complete output (40 lines):
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
running build_ext
building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall - 
g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack- 
protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC - 
DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100012 -DHAVE_LO64=1 - 
I/home/devfwecoapproot/ecoappapis/fwecovenv/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -I. - 
I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/10/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:0:
./psycopg/psycopg.h:34:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
#include <Python.h>
    ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.

You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
required for the build and try again.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg3
```

**I have tried these methods:**

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip and then pip3 install psycopg2
```

Comment: Please clarify you Ubuntu release, they are in *yy.mm* format, and 0 is not a valid month.

Comment: @guiverc it is: 18.04

Comment: I installed Psychopy to four different OS a few weeks ago : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212044/ubuntu-18-04-psychopy-segmentation-fault-core-dumped ..... My sketchy notes : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kqO48rdB4nzYgOp5IZ1OiWwLHsmkxEvx/view?usp=sharing